# Why are the maximal interval's endpoints semicontinuous functions of the initial condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the solution of the autonomous initial value problem

$$x' = f(x), \quad x(0) = x_0, \quad f \in C^1$$

as a function of $x_0$. Let $L(x_0)$ and $U(x_0)$ be the lower and upper endpoints of the maximal interval where the solution is defined. How do I show that $L$ and $U$ are upper and lower semicontinuous functions of $x_0$, respectively?

Comment: Do you know the following result: *If the solution $\varphi(\cdot;x_0)$ of the IVP $x'=f(x)$, $x(0)=x_0$ is defined (at least) on $[a,b]$, where $a<0<b$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any $\tilde{x}$ with $\lVert x_0-\tilde{x}\rVert<\delta$ the solution $\varphi(\cdot;\tilde{x})$ of the IVP $x'=f(x)$, $x(0)=\tilde{x}$ is defined (at least) on $[a,b]$.*? If you do, then showing that $L$ and $U$ are semicontinuous is a simple exercise. Can you continue now?

Comment: @user539887: Thanks! I know that the maximal interval has to be open. Hence $L(x) < a < 0 < b < U(x)$. And, yes, it is clear that, for $\delta$ small enough, we also have $L(x + \delta) < a < 0 < b < U(x + \delta)$. I can continue from there. :-)